# The format of the phone number provided is incorrent Please enter the phone number in a format that can parsed into E.164 format

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log in through my phone number and OTP using firebase and I am using the IntlPhoneField package to enter the number and select desired country code.
Here is how I am doing it

```
 IntlPhoneField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    showCountryFlag: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.greyColor),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.greyColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                    initialCountryCode: 'PK',
                    onChanged: (phone) {
                      setState(() {
                        dialCodeDigit = phone.countryCode;
                      });
                    },
                  )
```

And i am sending this code and phone number to provider like that

```
  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                  AddNewDialogBox.dialog(context, true);
                  context
                      .read<LoginPhoneProvider>()
                      .phoneSignInn(context, phoneController.text, dialCodeDigit);
                  print(dialCodeDigit);
               
                }
```

here is my code for getting OTP using provider state management and getting phone number and country code from login screen

```
Future<void> phoneSignInn(
      BuildContext context,
      String phoneNumber,
     String countryCode,
     // String countryCOde,
      ) async {
    TextEditingController codeController = TextEditingController();
    if (kIsWeb) {
      // !!! Works only on web !!!
      ConfirmationResult result =
      await _auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

      // Diplay Dialog Box To accept OTP
      showOTPDialog(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber + countryCode,
        //countryCode: countryCode,
        codeController: codeController,
        context: context,
        onPressed: () async {
          PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verificationId: result.verificationId,
            smsCode: codeController.text.trim(),
          );

          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
          Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Remove the dialog box
        },
      );
    } else {


      // FOR ANDROID, IOS
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber + countryCode,
        //  Automatic handling of the SMS code
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          // !!! works only on android !!!
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        },
        // Displays a message when verification fails
        verificationFailed: (e) {
          showSnackBar(context, e.message!);
        },
        // Displays a dialog box when OTP is sent
        codeSent: ((String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
          showOTPDialog(
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber + countryCode,
           // countryCode: countryCode,
            codeController: codeController,
            context: context,
            onPressed: () async {
              PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                verificationId: verificationId,
                smsCode: codeController.text.trim(),
              );

              // !!! Works only on Android, iOS !!!
              await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const DriverSginUpScreen()));
             // Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Remove the dialog box
            },
          );
        }),
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          // Auto-resolution timed out...
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

incase if you need to know about the dialog that I show after receiving OTP here is the code of OTP dialog

```
void showOTPDialog({
  required BuildContext context,
  required TextEditingController codeController,
  required VoidCallback onPressed,
  required String phoneNumber,
}) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: AlertDialog(
        title:  Text("Enter 6 Digit OTP send to\n$phoneNumber"),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            PinCodeTextField(
                pinTheme: PinTheme(
                  shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  fieldHeight: 60,
                  fieldWidth: 30,
                  activeFillColor:
                Colors.white,
                ),
                appContext: context,
                length: 6,
                controller: codeController,
              onChanged:  (value) {
                print(value);

                }
                ),

          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: const Text("Done"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

But I am getting an error related to phone format I don't know what I am doing wrong and how to resolve it here is an error that I receive after entering the phone number:

```
The format of the phone number provided is incorrent
Please enter the phone number in a format that can
parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are
written in the format [+|country code][subscriber
number Including area codel. Invalid format. 1
```

Comment: print out the phone number with country code you are sending to firebase. you need to send a phone number with the country code.

Comment: Yeah i guess i was sending number first and country code second so format was incorrect thank you